# Meteor - database for collections mapped to subdomain

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to meteor, but would like to map different URLs on my meteor site to a mongo collection.

company1.mysite.com - would read/write to a mongodb company1
company2.mysite.com - would read/write to a mongodb company2

Is there a way with meteor to do this? I'm hoping to map both subdomains to mysite.com and have a single application serving multiple subdomains.

Comment: Have a look at [partitioner](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-partitioner).

Answer (score 0):

Basic proof of concept you can find here: 
https://github.com/parhelium/meteor-so-db-collection-mapped-to-subdomain

There are 2 packages needed:

- mrt add iron-router
- mrt add inject-initial

### Server Side

Two example collection were created:

```
Company1 = new Meteor.Collection("company1");
Company2 = new Meteor.Collection("company2");
```

and filled with some data.

Another important step is to create hashMap (should be collection in real life) which maps **subdomain** to **collectionName**. Example :

```
var subdomainToCollectionName = {
    "localhost":"company2",
    "company1.localhost":"company1",
    "company2.localhost":"company2"
}
```

Later `Router` was used:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('matchSubdomains', {
        where: 'server',
        path: '*',
        action: function () {
            // filter requests to static files, like favicon.ico
            if(/(css|js|html|map|ico)/.test(this.path)) {
                console.log("Router.onAllRoutes: INVALID :   "+this.path)
                return;
            }
            console.log("Router.onAllRoutes: VALID :   "+this.path)

            // read subdomain from headers 
            var subdomain = this.request.headers.host.split(":")[0];

            var collectionName = subdomainToCollectionName[subdomain];
            if(collectionName){

                // injects to HTML name of the collection which should be used
                Inject.obj('collection', {name:collectionName} );

            }else{
                throw new Error("Cannot find collection for subdomain : " + subdomain);
            }

            this.next();
        }
    });
   });
```

One route was created which catch all possible routes and filter them. That route is executed only once when user opens application, later client side router is used.

### Client Side

On Client Side there is only one collection `Company` :

```
Company = new Meteor.Collection(Injected.obj('collection').name);
```

That collection is dynamically attached to collection mapped on server side from subdomain.

Hope that helps.